# InstanceContextMode of WCF

Tags: wcf, instancecontextmode

I have a Web service create by WCF, and it could response for the client's request, such as adding or updating data.

Let's call the main part of service *Context*, because some method(supposed method *A*) would spend a long time to handle, but I don't want the method *hold* the server, I set the *InstanceContextMode* enum to *PerCall*, and I expect that each time I call *A*, it will create a new instance to serve the request, then my server could continue to server other one's as usual.

But my problem is, it still use *Main thread(UI thread)* to serve each time, so when I call *A*, the server will stop response for a long time, till *A* done.

Did I miss anything? I'm a novice of WCF, so please let me know if I had any mistake.

Comment: If you have a long running process, then a web service is probably not the right way to do it.   The `InstanceContextMode` of the service (or any other setting of the service) has absolutely no connection with the client.  If you must use WCF for the long-running process, then a) make the call async so it doesn't freeze your UI, and b) make the service method a one-way call so the client isn't waiting for the long-running process to complete.

Comment: @Tim I have to apologize that I've might ask toward wrong direction... I should change _ConcurrencyMode_ rather than _InstanceContextMode_ for achieving my goal. Still appreciate for your advice, that gave me useful reference.